# Why does the following integral starts from $0$?

Tags: calculus, integration, power-series

Consider $$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{3n+1} x^{3n+1}$$

It's a power series with a radius, $R=1$. at $x=1$ it converges. Hence, by Abel's thorem:

$$\lim_{x\to 1^-} f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{3n+1}$$

Evaluating the derivative

$$f'(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{3n+1} (3n+1)x^{3n+1} = \ldots = \frac{1}{1+x^3}$$

Now, consider this claim: "Since $f(0) = 0$: $$f(x) = \int_0^x \frac{1}{1+t^3} \ dt$$

I am familiar with the fundamental theorem of calculus, yet not sure why this claim true, More presicely; Why is the integral starts at $0$?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fundamental theorem tells you that

$$f(x)=f(a)+\int_a^x f'(t) dt.$$

It's convenient to choose $a$ such that $f(a)=0$, because then

$$f(x)=f(a)+\int_a^x f'(t) dt = \int_a^x f'(t) dt.$$

Since your function is a power series with no constant term, it's not hard to see that you can use $a=0$ for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Note the following corollary:

> $$\int_a^b f(t)\, dt = F(b)-F(a)$$

You are free to choose the points $a$ and $b$ as long the function $f$ is defined in $[a,b]$. But choosing $a$ such that $F(a)=0$ simplifies things.